# implementing python code on GPU from spyder

Tags: python, cuda

According to knowledge `with tf.device('/GPU')` can be used for implementing tensor-flow in GPU. Is there any similar is there any way for implementing any python code on GPU(Cuda) ? or should I use pycuda?

Comment: There is no generic method to take arbitrary python code and make it run on a CUDA GPU.  you would need some sort of programming approach.  Tensorflow, numba, pycuda are some examples.

Comment: @Robert Crovella : When i was trying on MNIST dataset , i have used 'with tf.device('/GPU:0')'  command at the beginning of python code FOR RUNNING CODE ON GPU. But now i am just doing some python code with out making any tensors. so if i did the same, ie. writing 'with tf.device('/GPU:0') ath the top of the program does not make any sense, Right? i want to run my code on GPU(CUDA).

Comment: You'll need to learn more about how this works.  Just saying `with tf.device('/GPU:0')` does not mean that any arbitrary python code you write after that will RUN ON THE GPU.  But certain tensorflow activity that you invoke after that will run on the GPU.  If you want to make Python code run on the GPU, you'll need to learn more about how Tensorflow, or numba, or pycuda or some other approach like that work.  It is not as simple as putting `with tf.devce(...)` at the top of your python code.

Answer (score 3):

For parallel processing in python some intermideate libraries or packages needed to be there that sit between the code and the gpu/cpu for parallel executions. Some popular packages are *pycuda, numba* etc. If you want to do gpu programming using simple python syntax without using other frameworks like tensorflow, then take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPQnFXD7DxM).